# JavaScript Inheritance, Resetting the prototype constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Here's a basic example of instance inheritance:

```
function A() {
    this.props = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    }
}
A.prototype = {
    fn: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }
}


function B() {
    A.call(this);
}


B.prototype = Object.assign(A.prototype, {
    write: function() {
        this.fn();
    }
});

console.log(B.prototype.constructor); // ƒ Object() { [native code] }
B.prototype.constructor = B;
console.log(B.prototype.constructor); // ƒ B() { A.call(this); }

var b = new B();
```

And here's an example of the same functions without inheritance:

```
function A() {
    this.props = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    }
}
A.prototype = {
    fn: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }
}


function B() {

}
B.prototype = {
    write: function() {
        console.log('good')
    }
}

/* 
    I don't think anyone advocates setting the prototype constructor
    as the Function to which it belongs in this case.
*/ 
console.log(B.prototype.constructor); // ƒ Object() { [native code] }
B.prototype.constructor = B;
console.log(B.prototype.constructor); // ƒ B() {}

var b = new B();
```

As you can see, in both cases, before the line:

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

The prototype constructor is the native Object constructor and afterward it is the Object/Function which the prototypes were declared on.

Is the line in question necessary for older browsers, was it necessary to combat some popular bad techniques, or am I not doing prototypal inheritance correctly?

Comment: In both cases you are overriding `B.prototype` with a new object. So the `constructor` is gone (you have to reset it). You can add a `"constructor"` property to the object literal that you are assigning to `B.prototype` like: `B.prototype = { constructor: B, write: ... };`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ibrahim, for pointing out, that in both cases I was overriding B.prototype.

In light of this, it seems that:

1.

```
B.prototype = Object.assign(B.prototype, A.prototype, {
    write: function() {
        this.fn();
    }
});
```

2.

```
B.prototype = Object.assign(B.prototype, {
    write: function() {
        console.log('good')
    }
});
```

Should leave the original prototype constructor intact.

Comment: Object.assign is defined in the ES2015 spec, if the intention is to use in older browsers you will need a polyfill. Also, why not attach the functions directly to the original prototype? (B.prototype.write = fun...)